# Использование link16 для ассемблера

Tags: ассемблер

Не получается использовать `link16`. Программа написана для MS-DOS. Запускаю в командной строке `link16 1.obj`. Появляется:

> `Run File [1.obj]:
> List File:
> Libraries:
> Definitions File:`

Что туда писать? Я ничего не писал, нажимал Enter. Файл 1.com не создался.

Comment: Какая версия masm?

Answer (score 1):

Если вы работаете под 64-битной Windows, то и старые скомпилированные 16-битные программы (включая все .com) не будут работать. 16-битная подсистема не поддерживается (да и 32-битная Windows лишь частично поддерживает 16-битные приложения).

Зачем вам писать программы для устаревших архитектур? Если только в целях обучения, используйте виртуальные окружения (DOSBox, VirtualBox, etc.), ставьте нормальный DOS (FreeDOS) и работайте. В любом случае NTVDM не предоставляет полной совместимости.

Подробнее о различии 32-битных и 64-битных Windows, в том числе [о поддержке 16-битных приложений](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946765) на сайте Microsoft.

Comment: В учебнике MS-DOS рассматривается. Программу можно будет смотреть в отладчике. У меня 32 битная винда.

Comment: Тогда вариантов два:  
1. Взять, например, DOSBox и гонять ваши приложения (и все трансляторы, отладчики) внутри.  
2. Задуматься о смене учебника. Уж по 32-битным ассемблерам полно литературы и на русском языке. Тем более, что COM-приложения сейчас ну вообще никому не нужны.

Comment: Ну если по предмету надо (однако уже май на дворе), то деваться некуда. И где вы найдёте такие красивые модели памяти, как medium, large, huge? Да и .com как такой -- уже недоступен.

Comment: Мы у себя студентам лет уж, наверное, шесть, архитектуру ЭВМ рассказываем на примере IA-32 и ассемблера GNU as (в составе gcc).

Comment: Вы @Mr-Al зачёт поставите? (Кстати, as -- не в составе gcc. binutils, однако)

Comment: Мне не зачет, я так, для себя)

Comment: Тогда действительно dos-ассемблер лучше послать куда-подальше. Вы же не изучали русский язык с ятями и твёрдыми знаками в конце слов?